# Start screen wallpaper won't change

Tags: 8.1, settings, personalization

I'm trying to change my Start Screen Wallpaper but whenever I do the old one remains and nothing I do will update it.

Is there a way to manually force this or another approach I could take?

Comment: When you choose a new wallpaper, where are you choosing it from? the built-in selection, your camera roll or a remote source such as OneDrive?

Comment: From my camera roll

Comment: Is the photo saved on an SD card, or the internal memory?

Comment: @RowlandShaw Internal memory. Hard reset hasn't helped either.

Comment: Can you set one of the built-in images as a background (from the Backgrounds folder) ?